# How to dynamically add attribute and value in json data

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

```
[{"id":2,"name":"Paypal"},{"id":3,"name":"Scrill"}]
```

How to add dynamically new attribute and its value in here using php or in laravel framework. converted data is like

```
[{"id":2,"name":"Paypal","amount":"100"},{"id":3,"name":"Scrill","amount":"200"}]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your attempt.

Comment: Actually i don't understand how to add new attribute here. Please give me a solution. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Where have you researched?

Comment: I am not so expert so i asked here.

Comment: [***How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?***](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: I am googled but not get any proper solution. May be i was wrong to google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pseudo code:

```
Convert JSON string to PHP associative array.
Add / alter keys on PHP associative array.
Convert PHP associative array to JSON string.
```

I don't want to take all the fun away - so here are some links:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

;-)

---

**Update**: OP has requested a complete solution.

To convert the JSON string to a PHP associative array:

```
$decoded = json_decode($jsonStr, true);
```

Always check that things didn't go wrong:

```
if ($decoded === null) {
   die('Unable to decode JSON string: ' . $jsonStr);
}
```

Modify your PHP array:

```
$decoded[] = array(
   'id' => 3,
   'name' => 'Scrill',
   'amount' => 200
);
```

Finally re-encode to a JSON string:

```
echo json_encode($decoded);
```

Comment: i don't able to reach the solution until. Can you please give me solution?

Comment: @MahfuzShishir you can't do the research... what? Wally here has supplied you with EVERYTHING but actual code to *learn* for yourself. You're lucky you even had someone give you this much of a hint.

Comment: I find out the solution in another way.